# Backing up postresql database in openshift to outside the pod

Tags: postgresql, openshift, postgresql-10, pg-dump

Looking for some guidance/best practice on how to back up a postgresql database running in an Openshift pod. I've come across this rsync solution for application data - https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/admin_guide/backup_restore.html#backup-application-data - but was wondering how to use pg_dump?

I'd like the pg_dump to dump the database to a volume outside the pod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays best practice is most likely to use an Operator to run PostgreSQL on Kubernetes, for example with the [Crunchy Data PostgreSQL Operator](https://operatorhub.io/operator/postgresql).

If you do not want to use Operators, another option would be to use a `CronJob` to run `pg_dump` in a regular interval and put the dump on a `PersistentVolume` mounted to the Pod.